Radiant barrier to improve attic HVAC?
Does anyone have experience with adding a radiant barrier to the attic rafters to keep the attic HVAC cool in the summer? I've got a 2.5 ton unit that really struggles when the attic gets to 130F. Multiple roofers have confirmed my soffit and ridge vents are clear of debris and providing adequate ventilation and the attic floor is R60 and properly air sealed.

Forget the radiant barrier, put in a thermostatic controlled power ventilation fan.

Where is the indoor unit for your air conditioner located?

The evap and air handler are in the attic and struggle in the heat.
